# Navigationlink within dynamic List and custom navigationbar not popping back

Tags: foreach, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm experiencing a quite strange behavior from the `NavigationLink`.

When I'm setting the selection of the `NavigationLink` from outside the list to `nil` the view pops back. If I do the same thing from inside the `list` it's not working. Even when I'm in the child view and am setting it to the variable from outside the `list` and then to `nil` it works. It seems like that the child view is somehow forgetting about the `NavigationLink` within the `list`.

Solutions like this ([NavigationLink tag and selection not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65212801/navigationlink-tag-and-selection-not-working-as-expected?rq=1)) with the `@Environment(\.presentationMode)` are not working in the custom NavigationBar or at least I don't know how.

What am I missing here? Any help is much appreciated :)

**App entry:**

```
struct MainView : View {
    @ObservedObject var dbhandler = DBhandler()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Header()
                .frame(height: 50)
            
            NavigationDummy()
        }.environmentObject(dbhandler)
    }
}
```

**Environmental object for navigation and model:**

```
class DBhandler: ObservableObject {
    @Published var navSelection : String? = nil
}

struct DummyObject {
    var year: Int
    var names: [String]
}
```

**Custom NavigationBar:**

```
struct Header: View{
    @EnvironmentObject var dbhandler: DBhandler
    var body: some View{
        HStack{
            Button {
                dbhandler.navSelection = nil
            } label: {
                Text("Back")
            }
            Text("Current view: \(dbhandler.navSelection ?? "Empty")")
        }
    }
}
```

**Parent View:**

```
struct NavigationDummy: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dbhandler: DBhandler
    var dummyList : [DummyObject] = [DummyObject(year: 2020, names: ["Jo", "Alex"]), DummyObject(year: 2019, names: ["Mike", "Nancy"])]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                List{
                    ForEach(dummyList, id:\.year){ object in
                        Section(header: Text(String(object.year))){
                            ForEach(object.names, id:\.self) {name in
                                Button {
                                    dbhandler.navSelection = name
                                } label: {
                                    VStack{
                                        Text(name)
                                        NavigationLink(destination: ChildView(), tag: name, selection: $dbhandler.navSelection) {
                                            EmptyView()
                                        }.hidden()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: ChildView(), tag: "OutsideList", selection: $dbhandler.navSelection) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                
                Button {
                    dbhandler.navSelection = "OutsideList"
                } label: {
                    Text("Detail view from outside list")
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ChildView:**

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dbhandler: DBhandler
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Button {
                dbhandler.navSelection = "OutsideList"
            } label: {
                Text("Outside list")
            }
            
            Button {
                dbhandler.navSelection = "Jo"
            } label: {
                Text("Inside list")
            }
        }.navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The current workaround I use is to have a placeholder root NavigationLink in the Parent View like this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView(), tag: "Root", 
               selection: self.$dbhandler.navSelection,
               label: {
               EmptyView()
               }).hidden()
```

and then in the header do this to pop back:

```
    dbhandler.navSelection = "Root"
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
        dbhandler.navSelection = nil
    }
```

But that's not the ideal way ...